# How to make a triangle, rectangle, polygon in Android?

Tags: android, shapes

If I select shapes like **Triangle**, **Rectangle**, **Polygon**, **Curve** etc then it must be able to draw specific selected shapes. Like Paint (this is an application offered by Microsoft for creating shapes and sketches). In Android, I have to select the shapes and should be able to draw like a Free hand drawing but it completely should be done it in code wise.

Same: I have to `draw` either directly select the **triangle** shape from the options given, or  can `draw` a **triangle** of any base and `height` from scratch.

How could I do this in Android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenGL ES

Open [this](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html) link

Hope it will useful

Comment: How could i define different shapes like Rect, Square, triangle can placed it in Tool box like Ms-paint application.How to create tool box with different shapes and if i select specific shape then it should be able to perform drawing like paint application. how could i do this in android ?